# Как переместить все обьекты внутри GraphicsScene на определенное растояние. QtCreator

Tags: qtcreator

Есть кастомный класс `GraphicsScene`, который наследует `QGraphicsScene`. На нем есть круглешки( не `Items` ). Идея такова : при нажатии на кнопку и дальнейшем движении круглешки перемещаются ( относительно движения мыши ). в GraphicsView есть `translate` , есть ли что-то подобное в `QGraphicsScene`.

P.S Переопределять каждому круглешку координаты и перерисовывать очень не выгодно. Их тысячи

Comment: как они продвигаются? можно холст с крулешками продвинуть

Comment: То есть продвинуть ?

Comment: Например подвинул мышкой влево, а они все тоже влево. То есть в туже сторону что и мышка.